# Identification of code in eclipse helios

Tags: java, eclipse

How is possible to identify if a selected code is a method, a function, a variable...???

```
public class Modifiers implements IObjectActionDelegate{
private Shell shell;

public void run(IAction action) {
    SelectedText selectedText;      
    IEditorPart editor = getActiveEditor();

    if (editor instanceof AbstractTextEditor) {
        selectedText = getSelectedText(editor);

        //HOW TO IDENTIFY THE SELECTED CODE         
    }
}

public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {        
}

public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
    shell = targetPart.getSite().getShell();
}

private IEditorPart getActiveEditor() {
    return Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
            .getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
}

private SelectedText getSelectedText(IEditorPart editor) {
    SelectedText selectedText;

    try {
        final ISelection selection = editor.getEditorSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        final ITextSelection textSelection = (ITextSelection) selection;
        selectedText = new SelectedText(textSelection.getText(), textSelection.getOffset(), textSelection.getLength());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        selectedText = new SelectedText("", 0, 0);
    }
    return selectedText;
}
```

}

As you can see I have the selected code in `selectedText`. Now I want to know is how can I identify if the code in that variable is a method, a variable or whatever it contains.

When doing Refactors with eclipse it shows the code information you have selected. The idea is to do something like that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct,you need to simply move your mouse pointer on the code about which you want to get details, it will display a pop up window containing the details with specific symbol such as for static variable it will display 's' in that symbol or icon.

See carefully each symbol containing the different 2 letter and color has its own meaning.
i.e. **green for public**, **red for private** and **gray for local** etc.